# Angular Material 7 Error Resetting Autocomplete After Form Submit

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following material autocomplete field working. The issue is an error I get when resetting the form after successfully submitting data.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'company' of null
at MatAutocomplete.push../src/app/expense/expense-new/expense-new.component.ts.ExpenseNewComponent.displayFn [as displayWith] (expense-new.component.ts:93)
```

for some reason calling `this.expenseForm.reset` completely erases the displayWith directive data to null. Works fine on a fresh page reload.

My template:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="payee_id"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let payee of filteredOptions | async" [value]="payee">
      {{payee.company + " " + payee.first_name + " " + payee.last_name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

My submit function:

```
onSubmit(formData: any, formDirective: FormGroupDirective) {
   this.expenseForm.value.payee_id = this.expenseForm.value.payee_id.id ;
   this.expenseService.addExpense(this.expenseForm.value).subscribe( success => {
       this.errorMessage = null;
       this.dataService.updateDataTable('new expense success');
       this.expense_expense_categories_attributes.controls = [];
      formDirective.resetForm(); //workaround for error state not resetting
      this.expenseForm.reset();
     },
     error => {
       this.errorMessage = error;
       console.log(this.errorMessage);
       this.openDialog();
     });
 }
```

Autocomplete Filter Functions:

```
displayFn(payee?: Payee): string | undefined {
  if ((payee.company !== '' || null) && (payee.first_name !== '' || null  && payee.last_name !== '' || null)) {
    return payee ? payee.company  + ' - ' + payee.first_name + ' ' + payee.last_name : undefined;
  } else if (!payee.company) {
    return payee ? payee.first_name + ' ' + payee.last_name + ' ' + payee.company : undefined;
  } else if ((payee.company !== '' || null) && (payee.first_name === '' || null && payee.last_name === '' || null)) {
    return payee ? payee.company : undefined;
  }
}

private _filter(name: string): Payee[] {
  const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

  return this.payees.filter(option =>
   option.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0 ||
   option.last_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0 ||
   option.company.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `displayWith` function depends on the field having a value. Resetting your form removes the value from the field. Therefore, `payee` is null. This is not a problem and is normal - it is usually okay to have an empty field (value not yet selected). You just need to make sure your `displayFn` function handles that:

```
displayFn(payee?: Payee): string | undefined {

  if (!payee) {
    return '';
  }

  if ((payee.company !== '' || null) && (payee.first_name !== '' || null  && payee.last_name !== '' || null)) {
    return payee ? payee.company  + ' - ' + payee.first_name + ' ' + payee.last_name : undefined;
  } else if (!payee.company) {
    return payee ? payee.first_name + ' ' + payee.last_name + ' ' + payee.company : undefined;
  } else if ((payee.company !== '' || null) && (payee.first_name === '' || null && payee.last_name === '' || null)) {
    return payee ? payee.company : undefined;
  }
}
```

If your intention is to have a default value for the autocomplete so that it is not possible to have nothing selected, then you need to set that default value back on the `payee_id` control after resetting the form.